# catia knowledgeware Hole AnchorMode

Tags: catia

I everyone,

I'm trying to create a rule, to change the anchor point, controlled by a parameter, with knowledge advisor.

Hole anchor point

[image]

Anyone knows how to do it?

I'm new to knowledge advisor, where I can find the help or a guide?
Tiago Figueiredo
Tooling Engineer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property Anchor mode is not exposed for KBE. However it is for VB. So you can create a simple "VBScript with argument" feature which you can use to set the property.

[image: VB Script With Arguments feature]

Once you have this you will be able to control the attribute of the hole using with a Reaction linked to a parameter. In this example I created attributes on the holes using the parameters explorer tool and are using those for reaction triggers.

[image: Reaction Content]

Comment: By the way, there is any manual or guide that I can follow? I'm starting with Knowledge, so I need to learn everything.